# How to configure Acitve/Standby high availability for application deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I have to deploy an application in Kubernetes in Active/Standby High availability configurations.
How to do this using Kubernetes concepts?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. If your cluster goes down, all your environments will go down, and if your cluster is up, your primary app (the active one) is going to work just fine. So, I would say you are just wasting resources. It is not a k8s approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is no any native support for Active/Standby application deployment in Kubernetes.

Here is the feature request on Github.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45300

Comment: Is there any other way we can do it ourselves ?

Comment: Can you check the second answer listed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291581/kubernetes-service-with-clustered-pods-in-active-standby It suggest to make use of labels as an hack.

Answer (score 0):

front the two application instances using ha-proxy. ha-proxy supports active/standby mode

Comment: What is ha-proxy ? Is it an image , where ?

Comment: I cannot use 3rd party apps. Have to use only kubernetes concepts.